# Nuxt Auth 'loginWith' function doesn't send data to DRF

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I recently tried to combine Nuxt.js with Django. Nuxt.js has a module called Nuxt Auth (I use @nuxtjs/auth-next), which is pretty straightforward and simple to use.

However, I ran into a problem when I tried to get the post data when using `$auth.loginWith(...)` in a Django APIView. When I print out `request.POST`, it returns an empty QueryDict. When I log in with the standard DRF forms, I get my token as expected (I use JWT for authentication).

I first thought that I did something wrong in my Nuxt.js frontend, so I cloned some repos on GitHub to see how they have done it ([tickstudiu](https://github.com/tickstudiu/nuxt-local-auth), [ammezie](https://github.com/ammezie/nuxt-auth-app)). I then tried to combine their frontend with my backend. I also watched a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzUpO8tXoaw) on YouTube.

Still the same problem... That's why I think that it is a Nuxt + Django specific problem because otherwise, the other repos would work, right? Or maybe I just do something wrong every time...

This is what I get when I log in with standard DRF form:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
{
    "username": "admin",
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhbmRyZWFzLmdlcmFzaW1vdzEyQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTYyMjc5NjQ2N30.XQ58Fo0nOS2C44SRQG5A2vEDT0fOXJTIrHG8XNaxzBo"
}
```

Here is my Login API in Django:

```
class LoginAPIView(GenericAPIView):

serializer_class = LoginSerializer

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    print(request.POST) # prints an empty QueryDict

    username = request.POST.get('username', None)
    password = request.POST.get('password', None)

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user:
        serializer = self.serializer_class(user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response({'message':'Bad credentials!'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

This is the output in the console, when I try to log in with Nuxt:

```
<QueryDict: {}>
Unauthorized: /api/accounts/login/
[03/Jun/2021 10:35:28] "POST /api/accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 401 30
```

Here is my login form script in Nuxt:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      valid: false,
      userInfo: {
        username: "",
        password: "",
      },
    };
  },

  methods: {
    loginUser() {
    this.$auth.loginWith("local", {
        data: this.userInfo,
      }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
    },
  },
};
```

Here is a part of my `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
  ],

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
  },

  // authentication module configuration
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: 'accounts/login/', method: 'post', propertyName: false },
          user: { url: 'accounts/authenticate/', method: 'get', propertyName: false },
          logout: { url: 'accounts/logout/', method: 'post' }, // method: 'delete'
        },
        tokenType: 'bearer',
      }
    }
  },
  ...
```

I use Django 3.2.3,
DRF 3.12.4,
Nuxt.js 2.15.3,
and Nuxt Auth 5.0.0-1622309801.87126e3.

## EDIT:

Thanks to kissu, I found out that the CSRF Token is missing when I try to log in with Nuxt. Request payload:

```
{password: "some password", username: "admin"}
```

This is the request payload when I successfully log in with the standard DRF form. I found out that it uses `multipart/formdata` instead of `application/json` as standard. When I use the latter, it doesn't work.

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: X0FSeyS01dT8vgFK8eZhsXh5IYcDm8uGuqyh5XDOapoNMP8gZhQDcOacfsPYtsSp
username: admin
password: some password
```

I edited my axios configs to this:

```
axios: {
  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/',

  headers: {
    'X-CSRFToken': 'csrftoken',
  },
  xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
  xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken',
},
```

It still doesn't work but I now get a `400 Bad Request` error instead of 401. In the headers, I can find this: `X-CSRFToken: csrftoken`. That means the csrf token is not correctly inserted. However, it does get inserted correctly in a normal Vue app.

Good news: I found out that everything is working correctly when I inherit the standard Django `View` instead of DRF's `GenericAPIView` and Vue instead of Nuxt.

My question now is: How do I set up the csrf token in a Nuxt app and why doesn't it work with `application/json` in DRF? I found nothing on the Internet that worked in my case.

Comment: Not sure if it's the actual issue but you should set `/accounts/login/` rather than `accounts/login/` in your endpoints. Also, check what is send from the frontend via the network tab in your devtools to be able to debug it more easily.

Comment: I looked at the dev tools and found that the csrf token doesn't get sent correctly.